# Proof with div and curl

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator, curl

Let $$F, G:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$
Prove that:
$$\nabla\cdot(F\times G)=G\cdot (\nabla \times F)-F \cdot(\nabla\times G)$$

I found that:

$$∇\cdot(F×G)=(∂(F_2 G_3-F_3 G_2))/∂x+∂(F_3 G_1-F_1 G_3 )/∂y+∂(F_1 G_2-F_2 G_1 )/dz$$

and
$$G\cdot(∇×F)-F\cdot(∇×G)$$
$$=G_1  (∂F_3)/∂y-G_1  (∂F_2)/∂z+G_2  (∂F_1)/∂z-G_2  (∂F_3)/∂x+G_3  (∂F_2)/∂x-G_3  (∂F_1)/∂y-F_1  (∂G_3)/∂y+F_1  (∂G_2)/∂z-F_2  (∂G_1)/∂z+F_2  (∂G_3)/∂x-F_3  (∂G_2)/∂x+F_3  (∂G_1)/∂y$$
and
$$-G_2  (∂F_3)/∂x+G_3  (∂F_2)/∂x+F_2  (∂G_3)/∂x-F_3  (∂G_2)/∂x$$
$$=(G_3 ∂F_2-G_2 ∂F_3+F_2 ∂G_3-F_3 ∂G_2)/∂x$$

Comment: This is easier using [Levi-Civita symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Applications_and_examples).

Answer (score 1):

We can use multi-index notation. Note
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  \nabla\cdot (F\times G) & =\nabla_\mu(F\times G)^\mu=\partial_\mu\left(\epsilon^{\mu l k}F_lG_k\right)= \epsilon^{\mu l k}\partial_\mu(F_l G_k)= G_k \epsilon^{\mu l k}\partial_\mu F_l +F_l \epsilon^{\mu l k}\partial_\mu G_k \\
   &= G_k \epsilon^{k\mu l}\partial_\mu F_l -F_l \epsilon^{l\mu k}\partial_\mu G_k= G \cdot (\nabla \times F)-F \cdot (\nabla\times G)
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where we used the commutation properties of the symbol $\epsilon^{\mu l k}$.

Comment: So $$fϵ^{abc}= -fϵ^{cba}$$ ?

Comment: indeed, since this is an odd commutation.